# Appending plots to a HTML file in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am creating indiviual plots using df.plot on a dataframe. I can display them indiviually without any issues. I want to create an HTML doc with all plots.  Here is my pseudo code -

```
df=pandas.read_csv('file.csv')

## plot 1
df.plot(x,y)

## plot 2
df.plot(x,y)
```

Expected out - 1 HTML file with both plots 1 and 2

Comment: normally images are not part of HTML. They are in separated files .png, .jpg, .gif and HTML has tag `<img src="filename.png">` which inform browser where it should display image from "filename.png".

Comment: revised question.

Comment: You can manually export your plots to png, jpg etc. then append it to HTML doc, as @furas mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to save plot in file image .png and then you can use `<img src="filename.png">` in HTML to display this plot in browser

You can use `matplotlib` and `plt.savefig("filename.png")` for this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pandas.read_csv('file.csv')

## plot 1
df.plot(x,y)
plt.savefig('plot1.png')

## plot 2
df.plot(x,y)
plt.savefig('plot2.png')
```

Now you can create HTML file (ie. `index.html`) with tags `<img>` which will inform browser where to put plots.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>

   Some text

   <img src="plot1.png">

   Some text

   <img src="plot2.png">

</body>
</html>
```

So you will have three files: `plot1.png`, `plot2.png` and `index.html`